# Burn [remote-connection] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Just came across the [remote-connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remote-connection) when reviewing in the Triage review queue. The tag doesn't have a wiki (which really doesn't say anything, pro-or-con for keeping a tag or not) and there isn't many questions for it (76 at the moment).

The tag doesn't seem useful, when talking about programming you might have a remote connection to another server but I can't see it as a tag being particularly helpful for people looking for answers. The questions I have had a look at, I don't see them as any more helpful with this tag.

The tag itself sounds a lot more like something that would be on Super User or Server Fault rather than Stack Overflow.

Alternatively, maybe link it to the [network-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/network-programming) which makes more sense when referring to remote connections in a programming sense.

**EDIT:** After some more thinking about it, probably don't link it to the [network-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/network-programming) tag. The reason being, some people are using it when talking about SQL queries communicating to a remote SQL server which really has nothing to do with network programming however it still isn't relevant to have a [remote-connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remote-connection) tag on those questions either.

Comment: Agreed, +1. The distinction between local and remote connections is non-existent in principle, and 'connection' itself is just a part of networking.

Comment: Sure it's relevant to have a [tag:remote-connection] tag on the database questions. The tag seems to be mostly used by database questions, thus I propose that it simply be renamed to [tag:database-connection].

Comment: Does having a remote-connection/database-connection tag help those questions? Isnt it implicit that it requires a connection and the connection could be local or remote? People wanting to answer the question likely will find it by one of the SQL-specific tags like mysql, sqlserver, mariadb etc (in my opinion)

Comment: @Turnerj: Connecting to a database is not always straightforward.  The DB may need to be properly configured to allow such connections, and/or to authenticate properly (e.g. peer vs. password auth).  It is entirely possible for answerers to specialize in connection configuration.

Comment: In case [tag:remote-connection] is considered as not helpful, then [tag:remote] should be discussed, too.

Comment: @honk, agreed. There are only 7 questions for `remote` and they seem to refer to different things (from an IR remote, to a remote image, remote access, remote desktop) and each one has enough information in the body of the question to be both searchable and understandable without the additional `remote` tag. Not sure if that would be another burninate request though.

Comment: @Kevin, yeah connecting to a database might not be straight forward however I can't see the tag helping much. A well written question title and or question body would help the questions be identifiable. With how specific a `remote-connection` tag would be, I don't think there will be many people that specialise in just that. People that are skilled with the various SQL server implementations probably have a better chance of helping.