# Delete [remote-server]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, clean-up

There are over 700 questions currently tagged as [remote-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remote-server). This is a bad tag, because the phrase "remote server" is redundant. The term "server" already more or less implies that the server is remote from something (typically its clients); there's nothing significant which is added by the word "remote".

Once we remove the useless qualifier "remote", [server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server) is not a good tag for most of these questions. (It is perhaps not a good tag at all, but that's a discussion for another day.) It's simply far too broad; it can cover anything from system administration to questions about any number of specific network protocols or tasks.

None of the questions which are currently tagged as [remote-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/remote-server) appear to be usefully described by that tag. Many of them are asking questions about how to use, configure, or administrate server software, which is simply off-topic here — these are more appropriate for other sites, such as Super User or Server Fault. Of the rest, most of them are asking questions about how to connect to or interact with a specific type of remote server (often a database, FTP, SSH, or mail server), and hence are better described by tags specific to the task at hand (respectively, perhaps [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server), [ftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ftp), [ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssh), and [smtp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smtp)).

Please help me retag and/or close these questions.

Comment: The main issue is that the concept of that tag is way too broad.  It needs to die and everything in it needs more specific homes.

Comment: Get a shovel! I'm seeing several off topics ones just from the get go.

Comment: Similar to `remote-server`, there is also [`remote-connection`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281531/burn-remote-connection-tag) which is pretty bad (quality) though has far less questions.