# Drop [connections] and [connection]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

Apparently, the tag [connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connections) has 367 questions tagged with it. That's about 5% the amount of those tagged with [connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connection). And it has no wiki or and no synonym.

I browsed through some of them and the tag seems to be surprisingly used like [connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connection).

My guts tell me it should become a synonym of [connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connection).

---

EDIT after comment : Or maybe burninate both !

Burnination criterias :

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

Well it does describe some contents, but it is unambiguously ambiguous. Even in its description it may refer to database connection as well as web server vs web client connections.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

It can, but certainly not always.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Having a problem with connections in database is a specific information, having problem with websockets is a specific information... problem is that it is  ambiguous.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Well, by its wiki it always infers "transfer of data between to endpoints" ... But is it useful to classify questions ? And someone could think aabout other kinds of connections, like social networking. And now it doesn't mean the same thing at all.

Not sure about all these arguments, any insights by experimented people appreciated.

Comment: I'd say both should be removed. There are so many ways to connect, including social networks, data analysis, neural networks and other distinct knowledge domains.

Comment: Related (albeit, old) discussion on the [tag:remote-connection] tag here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281531/burn-remote-connection-tag?rq=1. That's another tag that, while _much more specific_ than the tags referenced above, probably doesn't mean much on its own.

Answer (score 6):

These tags don't really seem to contribute to anything.

If someone adds the tag "connection" it warrants further explanation. Connection to what? Under what conditions? With which database? In which language?

It doesn't contribute anything meaningful to the question beyond "Yeah, there's a problem with some kind of connection somewhere under some condition."

Besides, it seems that most of the on-topic questions for this tag (EG relating to programming and not "Meh computah won't connect") have to go into more detail to explain why the connection tag was included than they get from adding it to their question.

On top of that tags that reference specific topics (`python`, `C+`, `JavaScript`) allow experts in the field to filter, review and impart their knowledge onto others. I don't ever recall anyone referring to themselves as a "connection expert".

If this is to end in fire, then the tags shall burninate together.